# How to remove script name from address bar with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three domains, lets say frontend.com, platform.com, userpanel.com. Each one of them pointing to my server machine where index.php script makes redirection to frontend.php, platform.php, userpanel.php. Association between domain and scrip can be changed, it is stored in database and index.php checks it each time.

It works fine.

I would like to remove script name from browser address bar, to get frontend.com instead of frontend.com/frontend.php, platform.com instead of platform.com/platform.php and userpanel.com instead of userpanel.com/userpanel.php. How can I achieve it with Apache mod_rewrite?

Comment: Do you _need_ a redirect from your `index.php` – would it not be enough to just _include_ the desired file in there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.php [L]
```